# What are the rewards for collecting rainbow flowers?

Tags: offspring-fling

After earning my first rainbow flower (for beating the dev time), it told me that if I earn enough rainbow flowers I will "unlock my destiny". What is my destiny, and how many rainbow flowers do I need to unlock it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your destiny is [ULTIMATE Motherhood](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/OffspringFling/achievements/).
There are a few rewards for collecting rainbow flowers:

- Pretty flowers in your flower garden
- Gamer pride
- More levels!

According to the developer, quoted from [steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/211360/discussions/0/846956740673232550/), levels "111 - 120 are unlocked by getting rainbow times on 100 levels." This is similar to how levels 101-110 are unlocked by getting gold times on 100 levels.

Comment: Not to mention that there are 6 steam achievements that cannot be achieved without collecting the rainbow flowers on the first 100 levels (2 of which require 120 of them)